# Level editors compatible with MonoGame?

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm thinking about a future project using MonoGame and it seems there are no level editors that outright support it, though obviously there are those for XNA that may possibly be compatible.  So I suppose this is a two-part question; are there any existing level editors that can be made work with MonoGame, and also is it possible to create levels that are then inbuilt into the codebase and thus work cross-platform (for example, Android or iOS, or does the level editor have to support the platform)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A generic level editor that works with all kinds of games which can be made using MonoGame is just as feasible as a universal language translator (aka babelfish). In other words: you have to create your own level editor for your own game.

Comment: 2d or 3d? Tile-based or not? Even Microsoft Paint could be used as a level editor if you color-code entities into pixels.

Comment: I wrote a script to export level data laid out in Blender, useful until/unless you write a custom level editor for your game https://jhocking.itch.io/dropper-for-blender

Answer (score 1):

[tIDE](https://colinvella.github.io/tIDE/) can be ported to MonoGame quite easily.

Also [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140905074053/https://tide.codeplex.com/discussions/394847) discussion might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you will have to write your own level editor, or at least a portion of it. Unity3D is a very spectacular program, in that it is an engine, but also a generic and flexible platform for creating level editing solutions. Myself, and others I work with have used Unity3D to develop levels for various 3D platforms such as the Xbox, and we are currently using it to push content into the Havok Vision engine (post development goal). You will still have to design the constraints, formats, and loading procedures yourself though.